# geninterrupt() исходник для линукс

Tags: c, linux, ассемблер, gcc

Есть порт `geninterrupt()` на линукс? Нужен исходник, который принимает `gcc`. Нигде найти не могу. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не удивительно что не находите.

Во-первых, это вообще не функция, а макрос, вся суть которого заключается в генерации соответствующей команды `int XYZ` и подстановки её в исходник. 
Например, фрагмент `dos.h` из Borland C 3.1:

```
    /* These are in-line functions.  These prototypes just clean up
       some syntax checks and code generation.
     */
...    
void        _Cdecl          __int__( int __interruptnum );
...
#define geninterrupt( i ) __int__( i )      /* Interrupt instruction */
```

То есть никакой "функции" `geninterrupt()` не существует, как и "объявленной" `__int__()`, это внутренние заглушки компилятора.

Во-вторых, раз уж он живёт в `<dos.h>`, то вряд ли это про Linux.

Но если очень хочется, то [вот вариант для gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368909/gcc-inline-asm-input-variable):

```
void  geninterrupt (int x) {
  __asm__("  movb %[x], %%al \n"
          "  movb %%al, genint+1 \n"
          "  jmp genint \n"
          "genint: \n"
          "  int $0 \n"
         : /* no outputs */
         : [x] "m" (x) /* use x as input */
         : "al" /* clobbers %al */
         );
}
```

UPD, пояснения.

На самом деле инлайн-ассемблер в gcc может выглядеть не очень привычно для тех, кто привык к досовским компиляторам и их потомкам. Но это - отдельная тема. Если немного упростить, то ассемблерную вставку в gcc нужно воспринимать как отдельную функцию, у которой есть свой вход, свой выход, которой не видны внешние переменные вызывающей процедуры и т.д. Вот вся эта свистопляска с квадратными/круглыми скобочками, двоеточиями и прочим в конце и занимается обеспечением связи ассемблерной вставки с окружающим миром. Ссылки на подробности про эти загогулины (англ):

1. [GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html)
2. [Extended Asm - Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)

Дальше - про `jmp genint`. Нижесказанное актуально для старых процессоров, но раз уж мы повели речь о технологиях древних :-) В приведённом фрагменте кода меняется команда непосредственно в памяти. То есть буквально берём байт `CDh`, сразу за ним  записываем содержимое `x`, в результате получаем, например, `CDh 80h`. То есть - готовую команду `int 80h`. Но процессор может её просто не заметить! Потому что уже прочитал этот кусок памяти и начал готовиться к его исполнению (упреждающая выборка). Для того, чтобы исполняемая память была перечитана заново, нам и нужен этот "бессмысленный" переход (инструкции типа `call` или `jmp` делают предварительную выборку команд бессмысленной и заставляют железяку пересмотреть её).

Comment: Неплохо бы прояснить ассемблерный код (что конкретно там происходит и зачем вообще нужен jmp на следующую команду).

Comment: Ну вот и выросло поколение, которое не знает зачем нужен `jmp $+1` :-) (шутка). Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @klopp: Насколько мне помнится, уже на пентиумах конвейер было невозможно задетектировать программным путём by design, так что предосторожность с `jmp` вроде бы излишняя на 2015 год.

Comment: Да кто ж его знает, зачем этот код понадобился. Раз уж окаменелость уровня `dos.h` всплыла - не удивлюсь, что речь о 486 или 386 :-)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!